# Userform bottom exceeds Image bottom

Tags: excel, vba, image, size, userform

In Excel (VBA involved) I make a Userform, whose properties I set to Height = 720 & Width = 1280.
In Photoshop I have made a graphic, Width = 190 & Height = 720, intended for background of the sidebar menu.
I would expect, since the Userform & graphic have the same height, that the graphic covers a small verticla area all the way from up to down. Yet the Userform seems to have blank space under the bottom of the sidebar. The blank space is white, while the rest of the Userform is light blue.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how I may be able to fix it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Take a print screen of the form, edit the background image to match the screen shot and try using that image as the background to see if it fits/works.

Comment: I did. The sizes could be matched by the image I could make in Photoshop, yet in the long term would not provide a secure solution for more apps.

However, it turned out that the whole issue was a matter of conversion between pixels and points ; 96 pixels is 72 points, I had made the image in Pixels but the userform size numbers refereed to points.

In the end, (1280x720) pixels equals to (960x540) points. Once I entered the correct numbers in Excel VBA the problem was solved.

Plus the above numbers include the userform's window title bar.

Thank you for your attention and support !

Comment: You could add this as an answer and mark it as solved, this way someone who searches a similar question will see this answer.